# Capture packets from other machines in local network

Tags: networking, mac, tcp

Is it possible to capture packets from other local machines on my Mac? They are primarily all wireless as well, if that makes it any easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac has built in command for that

```
sudo tcpdump -A -s0 -ien0 port 80
```

-A : display the packets' contents as text
-s0 : capture entire packets not just the headers
-ien0 : capture packets in first ethernet interface,wireless is en1
port 80: capture packets only in port 80

Official [apple page here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3994)

other tools:

1. [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
2. [Cocoa packet analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/)
3. [Packet peeper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetpeeper/)

Another useful [article can be found here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-19212)

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools designed to do that sort of thing, such as Wireshark, on ethernet you may need to make some [network hardware changes](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet#Capture_using_an_Ethernet_hub) for packet capturing.